# ios Audio Unit kAUVoiceIOProperty_DuckNonVoiceAudio error -10879

Tags: ios, audio, audio-streaming, audiounit

I use Novocaine framework https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine, if I pause input unit (but output is working) from mic and then play it again in result I get echo. In apple documentation I see Voice-Processing I/O Audio Unit Properties - kAUVoiceIOProperty_DuckNonVoiceAudio. I try:

```
UInt32 zero = 0;
CheckError( AudioUnitSetProperty(inputUnit,
                                 kAUVoiceIOProperty_DuckNonVoiceAudio,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                 kInputBus,
                                 &zero,
                                 sizeof(UInt32)), "ERROR");
```

in method setupAudio
in result I have

```
ERROR (-10879)
```

In documentation I don't find description. In general, how I can make implement echo cancellation in iOS for audioUnits? I think problem maybe not in this property (becouse by default it should be enabled).. I find this great article - http://atastypixel.com/blog/developing-loopy-part-2-implementation/ author say about correlation signals and their subtraction..  for this case I think I need adaptive filter, but if it possible implement for iOS?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I find answer why this error occurred: in Novocaine AudioComponentDescription init as:

```
inputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
```

but in my my case correct:

```
inputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
```

After some experiments I concluded that after using kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO echo disable but not completely. May be I don't correctly use it.